# HealthKit Background Task Not Firing Properly

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, healthkit

I'm trying to send users a notification when they reach a certain step count.

I'm using the HealthKit `enableBackgroundDelivery` method to set this up and trying to get a number from `UserDefaults` to determine what the target step count should be and comparing to the current number from the health store.

For some reason, this isn't working and I have no idea how to debug it. I've managed to get it working without fetching the value from user defaults and just hard-coding something.

I'm triggering this function below from a swift ui view onAppear when the user opens the app. When it runs, I see it gets the right value printed from user defaults, both my `stepInterval` and `count` are Int. I can't see how the `stepInterval` variable wouldn't be available when it runs again in the background but that its ok running with a hardcoded value, I'm pretty sure my permissions are fine. What is the scope of the background delivery completion? What could I be doing wrong?

```swift
func setupBackgroundTracking() {
    let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
    print("quantity")
    
    guard let lastRedemption = Config.userLastRedemptionTime,
            let stepInterval = Config.userLevelStepInterval else {
        print("couldn't read config")
        return
    }
    print("config: \(lastRedemption), \(stepInterval)")
    
    healthStore.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: quantityType, frequency: .hourly) { (success, error) in
        if !success {
            if let error = error {
                print("failed to get steps \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            print("failed to get steps - no error")
            return
        }
        
        print("config inner: \(lastRedemption), \(stepInterval)")
        fetchStepsSince(lastRedemptionTime: lastRedemption, now: Date()) { count in
            print("step count was \(count)")
            if count >= stepInterval {
                print("starting to schedule notification")
                scheduleNotification(lastRedemption: lastRedemption)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Config user defaults access is defined as follows

```swift
class Config {
    static var userLevelStepInterval: Int? {
        get {
            return self.userDefaults.object(forKey: "userLevelStepInterval") as? Int
        }
        set {
            self.userDefaults.set(newValue, forKey: "userLevelStepInterval")
        }
    }
...
```

And my `scheduleNotification` function is as follows:

```
func scheduleNotification(lastRedemption: Date) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    
    let (title, body) = getRandomUserMessage()
    
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    print("scheduling Notification")

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("could not send notification \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        print("added notidication ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Could `Config.userLastRedemptionTime` be nil?

Comment: That seems to print with the right date. But not 100% when running in the background.

Comment: i've tried hardcoding the values again but can seem to get it to ever trigger like I thought I had it doing before. Kind of doubting that its even set up properly at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly suspicious of this line:

```
return self.userDefaults.object(forKey: "userLevelStepInterval") as? Int
```

You mean this to be an Int, so this should be:

```
return self.userDefaults.integer(forKey: "userLevelStepInterval")
                         ^^^^^^^
```

It is possible that it all "just works" because it winds up round-tripping through NSNumber anyway, but I would start with using the right types.

I also recommend using OSLogger rather than print, so you can watch the output via Console. (Or write this stuff directly to a log file that you can copy off-device, which is often my solution, but OSLogger has gotten easier to use.)

As always with debugging, make the system simpler and simpler to see what's going on. Make a simpler app that just does this one thing. Don't worry about actually reading the steps; just use logging to confirm that it gets launched in the background and can read a UserDefaults value you can read in the foreground. Add a lot of logs.

Comment: Thanks. Good spot. It should be an integer. Also with the proper logging, have switched to that also. Still, no luck, will try writing logs to a file like you suggest.

Comment: I recommend testing the individual parts of your system independently to rule out any issues with HealthKit, UserDefaults, or background execution. Consider setting up tests or smaller applications that focus on these areas one at a time. UserDefaults: The UserDefaults ex data should be immediately accessible after you've set it, but it's not guaranteed in every case, especially when your app is in the background. It's always good to make sure you synchronize UserDefaults after setting a value, using UserDefaults.standard.synchronize(). This forces the system to save your changes immediately.

Comment: test healthkit data access too and Background Execution. each independently By verifying each of these parts independently, you can hopefully identify which part is causing the problem.